# How do you find the center of a cake with just a knife?

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

Consider an undecorated cylindrical cake and a perfect knife.  We want to find the center of the cross-sectional circle.

If we can only score the surface of the cake, this reduces to finding the center of a circle with just a straightedge, [which is impossible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56457/determine-the-centre-of-a-circle).

But using a knife allows additional constructions.  For example, [Sarvesh Iyer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/316409/sarvesh-ravichandran-iyer) mentions:

> The big difference between straight lines on a circle and knives on a cake is that you can shift any cake pieces you cut, around the shape and match them up with other pieces. The piece that's in a darker shade of orange can be removed and used to replicate that particular angle around the center subtended by it. I don't think one can create duplicate angles with just a straightedge, hence the difference.

Similarly, YNK claims that

[image: Cake cut sevenfold]

determines the center in seven cuts, although he has not explained the construction procedure.

Here are some rules modeling our use of the knife.

1. You can't guarantee any nice properties of the lines like being perpendicular or parallel to another, just chords.
2. The "canvas" for connections is only the circle (you can't be cutting the table, just the cake).

What is the minimal number of cuts necessary to find the circle?  Is it YNK's 7?

Comment: @GerryMyerson because your cannot guarantee lines are perpendicular

Comment: @justaguy The accepted answer given there should apply directly to this problem.

Comment: Did you actually read everything at that link, grep? The perpendicularity problem is discussed.

Comment: @XanderHenderson This comment comes to you from a post recently closed citing duplication as the reason. According to my opinion, I formed after analysing the question, this is not a duplicate, but a question with a twist. It is true that the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56457/determine-the-centre-of-a-circle) cited as the original has no answer. Because of the twist added to the closed question, it has an answer. The twist allows us to carve out a tool from the cake using a knife and this tool makes it possible to form a procedure to find the center of the cake.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I kindly suggest you to consider opening this post unless 
the rules of MSE prevent you from doing so.

Comment: @YNK, you can't ping someone who has not taken part in the discussion of the question. There's no reason to expect Xander will see your comment. Also, Xander had no rôle in closing this question. What you can do is you can edit the question to make it crystal clear why it's not a duplicate. That will put it in the Review Queue, and users will be able to decide whether to reopen.

Comment: Some interesting variations on cake-cutting at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.11458.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for your advice and the link. I had edited the post as you have suggested. Perhaps, my edit is too naïve to get this post open. Hope nobody makes fun of it.

Comment: @YNK your edit should be good enough to show it's not a duplicate (provided the reviewers read carefully), but doesn't it also provide the answer to the question?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, it does, but without explaining how the chords were drawn. I think I have run out of steam. So let's close this thread.

Comment: @YNK Keep this alive : it has three reopen votes. The big difference between straight lines on a circle and knives on a cake is that you can shift any cake pieces you cut, around the shape and match them up with other pieces. The piece that's in a darker shade of orange can be removed and used to replicate that particular angle around the center subtended by it. I don't think one can create duplicate angles with just a straightedge, hence the difference. Let me know if I'm right.

Comment: If you allow moves such as placing the arc of a piece of the cake tangent to a straight cut, I think it can be done in five cuts.

Comment: @David, show us how!

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer You have just described the twist I was trying to describe in my comments and edit to the last letter.

Comment: Since you've specifically described the cake as *cylindrical*, why not take advantage of the third dimension? Viewing the cake side-on shows a rectangle; cutting along the diagonals of this rectangle gives two planes that meet at a line through the center of the cake. Viewing side-on from another angle, cutting along just one more diagonal gives a third plane that then determines the cake's center. Done!

Comment: @GerryMyerson Done, though it ended up only 4 cuts.

Comment: @Blue To actually put the ends of the knife on the diagonals of the rectangular cross-section you'd first have to cut the cake perfectly in half. So instead I suppose you are standing infinitely far away (to see a rectangle and not some rounded shape) and lining up the knife by eye. Then you have to make a cut perfectly parallel to your line of sight. Having done all that, in three cuts you've found the center of the cylinder but not the center of a circular face, whereas other constructions found the center of the circle but not the cylinder.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: CenterOfCake]

The seven figures given above show how we can determine the center of a cake by drawing seven line segments with a knife. In a few hours time, I will add text to this answer describing things like why we need to cut a portion segment that subtend an angle greater than $90^o$. So the interested parties can get themselves ready with a cake and knife similar to those shown in the diagrams given below.

[image: Cake and Knife]

Answer (score 6):

In the seven-cut answer we are able to use pieces of the cake for such things as measuring an equal chord inside the circle. In this answer I assume we can also do such things as place two pieces so that their arcs are tangent to each other.
The construction then uses four cuts.

Given a cake with center $A$, first cut off a segment along the chord $BC.$
This is the first cut.

[image]

Move the segment so it lies along the arc $BD$ and cut along the chord $BD.$
This is the second cut.

[image]

Place one of the cut-off segments along the chord $BC$ but with the arc facing "inwards". Place the other segment so that one end is at $C$ and the arcs of the two cut-off segments are tangent at $C.$
Let $E$ be the other end of the second segment's arc; cut along the line $BE.$
This cuts the circle along diameter $BF.$ This is the third cut.

[image]

Explanation: The angle between the chord $BC$ and the arc $BC$ is half the angle of arc $BC$, which is also half the angle of arc $BD$, which is the angle $\angle BCD,$ so the "inward facing" chord $BC$ is tangent to $CD.$
Triangle $\triangle BCE$ is isosceles with $BC=CE$ and $CD$ bisects $\angle BCE,$ so $CD$ is perpendicular to $BE,$ so $BE$ is the perpendicular bisector of $CD$ in isosceles triangle $\triangle BCD$ inscribed in the original circle.

Move one of the segments so that it lies along the arc $FG$ on the circle.
Make a cut from $G$ to $C$. This cuts the circle along diameter $CG.$
This is the fourth cut.

[image]

The center of the circle has now been located at the intersection of the last two cuts.

Explanation: as chords $BD$ and $FG$ are congruent, chord $DG$ is parallel to diameter $BF$ and therefore also perpendicular to chord $CD.$
Triangle $\triangle CDG$ is therefore a right triangle with hypotenuse $CG.$

Incidentally, it is not necessary to be able to make the cuts exactly parallel to the cylindrical axis of the cake. We can turn the cut-off segments upside down after cutting so that when we place them on the top of the cake they will occupy the correct regions.
The last two cuts would still intersect at the center of the circle on the top of the cake, but not necessarily intersect along the cake's cylindrical axis.